# Android - Switch to an activity using Intent and then change TextView's text on the switched activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, textview

I have a three different activities all of whom switch to a common Activity via Intent, with only minor modifications in the appearance of the *child* or *switched-to* Activity. I want to change the text of the `TextView`, so that each time the child activity displays a different text based on which activity it was switched-to from.
I have tried using this:

```
Button startSendingLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wmb_start_sending_button);
        startSendingLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ll_wmb_Map.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                TextView bmo_map_toolbar_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wmb_toolbar_title);
                bmo_map_toolbar_title.setText(R.string.ll_bmo_toolbar_title);

            }
        });
```

But this doesn't update the text in the `TextView`. Am I doing it wrong ?

1. Should I create three different Activities with their own layouts to achieve this ?
2. Will I be able to add or update a few views, differently, based on the activity I am switching from ?

I thought switching to the same activity via Intent will be a good idea for code-reusability and some efficiency gains as the *child* activity makes use of a `MapFragment` in all the three cases.

`ll_wmb_Map.class` : The common activity that is being switched to, using `Intent`
`wmb_toolbar_title` : The id of the `TextView` I want to change
`ll_bmo_toolbar_title` : The text I want to set in the `TextView`

Comment: is textView is the only change that you need to change?

Comment: `TextView` and then set the visibility of some Buttons to off and show another `TextView` instead.

Comment: You can't change the Views from different Activities. You set the content view in onCreate of each Activity. Seems strange that you wouldn't use a common  Fragment attached to one activity, if you're talking code reusability with some sort of callback to update a text view ..

Comment: when you as assign bmo_map_toolbar_title, it is still in your first activity.. you should assign it in onCreate

Comment: @MarkKeen Ok, that is what I was looking for. Because I thought maybe it was possible, but thanks for clearing that out. 
I'll try doing it the Fragment way. So , I have to create a single Fragment for the common activity and modify the fragment according to the activity it comes from ? Am I right ? I am sorry if it is a stupid question but I am really scared of Fragments.

Comment: @HandrataSamsul Ok, I understood, thanks, I didn't know that it can only be changed in that activity's `onCreate`.

Comment: @Yankee Check my answer below, Might be you are looking for the same.

Comment: If there is only few changes, I suggest you just follow the answer from @Archana, no need to use fragment.

Comment: If all you want to do is change a textview, that is for one Layout/Activity only I.e. updating a texviews content - a child view from the layout defined in onCreate (set content view)then you can do this by just updating its `setText` attribute, as long as the textView is a defined Local/Instance variable.

Comment: @BruceNguyen But Bruce , her answer states exactly what I have done, without the Intent-switching part. And if there is no switching to the child Activity, why would it even matter if the text gets changed.

Comment: @MarkKeen Yes, that's the solution. If I set the TextView in the onCreate of the child activity to `public` , I would be able to change it from any other Activity.

Comment: @Yankee, not quite. Think of Activities as separate entities entirely, that talk to each other through Intents. You will only have one Activity/Layout visible at a time. When you call startActivty you are saying I want to stop what I'm doing in this Activity, and start a new one, inflating it's layout, and passing control over to it. I would put some logging statements into some life cycle call backs (onCreate/onDestroy/onPause/onStop) to get some idea of what's going on. Look at this diagram - http://www.javatpoint.com/images/androidimages/Android-Activity-Lifecycle.png

Answer (score 1):

Fine, If you just want to enable/disable the view and change the textview content, you just need to use enable and disable functionality within onclick listeners instead of calling the same activity again and again.

```
 startSendingLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        bmo_map_toolbar_title.setText(R.string.ll_bmo_toolbar_title);

        //enable/disable the views
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes, I was going to do the same but as Mark has pointed out above that I can't make any changes to the Views from a different Activity. But thanks for the help Archana.

Comment: I think there is no need to use different activity.

Comment: But this way it isn't even switching to the new Activity. What's the use of changing the TextView when I am not even able to switch to that activity ?

Comment: If you want to reuse the same code then use this way. If there is a small change on view,  then no need to create a separate activity. You can just update the view with what ever changes you want.

Comment: I'm sorry Archana but you didn't get me. There are 3 activities and 1 another activity, the 3 activities are entirely different from the 1 activity. But all the 3 activities are switching to the single activity, with only minor differences in the appearance of the single activity, depending upon which activity it comes from.